# Dynamic lists as function arguments

Tags: programming, dynamic

Suppose I have a function that requires a list is as input. I.e.

```
f[list_]:=DoSomethingWithList
```

Now, if I pass a variable as Dynamic like this

```
pts={{0.1,0.1} , {0.5,0.1}, {0.1, 0.5}};
f[Dynamic[pts]]
```

everything works as expected as long as I don't use parts of the list. If I use a part of a list then things no longer work as expected ( by me ).

Another example

```
g[point_] := Slider2D[point]
p = {.1, .1}
g[Dynamic[p]]
Dynamic[p]
```

that works as expected, and this one

```
g[point_] := Slider[point[[1]]]
p = {.1, .1}
g[Dynamic[p]]
Dynamic[p]
```

that does not.

**Question: What behaviour of Dynamic explains the above?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try to just follow the flow of your replacements, then you clearly see what's going wrong. In you first definition everything goes as you expect:

```
g[point_] := Slider2D[point]
g[Dynamic[p]] =  (* Becomes => Slider2D[Dynamic[p]] *)
```

But in the second case you are stripping away the `Dynamic` tag:

```
g[point_] := Slider[point[[1]]]
g[Dynamic[p]] (*Becomes =>Slider[Dynamic[p][[1]]]  Which becomes => Slider[p]*)
```

Note: This is why your output is `Slider[{0.1, 0.1}]`.

If you want slider Dynamically editing `point[[1]]` you need the `Dynamic` wrapper to be around it, so you would do:

```
g[point_] := Slider[point /. Dynamic[var_] :> Dynamic[var[[1]]]]
p = {.1, .1}
g[Dynamic[p]]
Dynamic[p]
```

Though I would personally define this as:

```
g[Dynamic[point_]] := Slider[Dynamic[point[[1]]]]
```

Simply to make it clear that I'm defining the behavior for dynamically changeable variables.

Comment: I go for how you do it personally. Dynamic is what makes Mma powerful AND difficult, if you ask me.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this helps to see what is going on:

```
f[l_] := {Head[l], Head[l[[1]]]};
pts = {{0.1, 0.1}, {0.5, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.5}};
f[pts]
f[Dynamic[pts]]
```

gives

```
(*
{List, List}
{Dynamic, List}
*)
```

Why? Because even though `Dynamic[{1,2,3}]` gets printed as `{1,2,3}`, this is just output formatting; in reality, it remains `Dynamic[{1,2,3}]`. This is why when you look at the `Head` of the dynamic object passed to `f` you see `Dynamic`, but if you look at its first part you see `List`.

In summary then, putting `Dynamic` around an expression changes its head, even though it is still displayed as if the `Dynamic` wasn't there.

Another way to see this is to evaluate `Dynamic[x]` then select the output cell and shift-cmd-E to show what it is:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What I see is that Head works on part of list with Dynamic in front of it. Then why, for example, doesn't Slider work on that part?

Comment: what do you mean? What do you expect `Slider[{.1,.1}]` to do?

Comment: Thanks, jVincent already explained it in his answer. I am clearer on Dynamic now.