# Performing operations on function lists

Tags: dynamic, graphics3d

I am exploring the use of `Dynamic` variables for the `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical` options in a `Graphics3D` object.  I have the following code:

```
vp = {0, -5, 0}
vv = {0, 0, 1}
(* Cell break here to make changes in vp and vv a bit easier *)
img = Graphics3D[{Yellow, Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 3, 1}], Blue, 
  Cuboid[{2, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 3}]}, SphericalRegion -> True, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp],
  ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]]
(* Another cell break, but hopefully making cut and paste easier by adding comments *)
{ViewVertical, ViewPoint} /. AbsoluteOptions[img]
```

There are two things that bother me:

1. The `AbsoluteOptions` line throws an error ViewPoint::nlist3 is not
   a list of numbers.  I presume this is because the `Head` of vp is
   `Dynamic`.  This error isn't thrown for ViewVertical, however, which
   I would expect should complain as well.  Am I missing something, or
   can the `ViewVertical` error be safely ignored? (I don't like
   quieting errors for fear of covering up something later on down the
   line.)
2. Because of the dynamic head, operations on vv and vp require
   a bit of manipulation.  For example, in the next bit of code, the
   first line doesn't work and the second line does, but obviously the
   dynamic evaluation has been lost:

.

```
Norm[ViewVertical /. AbsoluteOptions[img]]
Norm[(ViewVertical /. AbsoluteOptions[img]) /. {Dynamic -> List}]
```

Again, I worry about my hack to change Dynamic into a List isn't the most elegant (or safe) way to gain access to these values.  Furthermore, I envision wanted to maintain the Dynamic nature of the data manipulation.  Any suggestions would be welcome.

P.S. I have looked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9175) for some guidance, and while helpful in framing the picture, I'm still a bit confused with the use of Dynamic in this case.

Comment: Why do You need to use `AbsoluteOptions` if those values are in `vv` and `vp` and Norm@vp is enough? If You just want to extract those values it seems to be a [duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3538/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Heh, it looks like you caught me just copying and pasting examples without giving much thought to what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring Kuba's Gordian Knot solution (let's just pretend he never said anything), I think the idiomatic function here would be `Setting`, which "collapses" `Dynamic` expressions:

```
{ViewVertical, ViewPoint} /. AbsoluteOptions[Setting[img]]
```

This can in turn be dynamic:

```
Dynamic[{ViewVertical, ViewPoint} /. AbsoluteOptions[Setting[img]]]
```

Neither of these trigger the `ViewPoint` error, which is pretty quirky. Just doing `AbsoluteOptions[img]` gives that error.

$\tiny-$

Sidenote, also check out `DynamicSetting`, which has some nifty debugging/development uses (see the color swatch example [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DynamicSetting.html)).

Comment: I'm glad You ignored me because this answer is educational :).

Comment: Thanks. I was unfamiliar with `Setting` and the dynamic version.