# Manipulate lists as function arguments

Tags: manipulate, programming, dynamic

I am trying to write a Demonstration, which I believe means I must write it as a Manipulate, not a DynamicModule. My question is essentially the same as "[Dynamic lists as function arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/dynamic-lists-as-function-arguments)", but I cannot figure out how to get the answer given there to work inside a Manipulate.

Below is a minimal non-working example that indicates what I am trying to accomplish. Basically, I want to use a HorizontalGauge with a list of two values as a Control object in a manipulate. I first tried using an IntervalSlider, but I need to do some computing with the values of the interval's endpoints and as far as I can tell, the TrackingFunction option does not work with IntervalSlider. At least the function I provided never seemed to get called, whereas functions I provided to Slider the same way work fine.

```
h[Dynamic[point_], opt___] :=
 Dynamic[HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[point][[1]]]]

Manipulate[
 {pt},
 {{pt, {0.6, 0.7}}, 0, 1, (h[##]) &}
 ]
```

The above displays correctly, but does not allow me to move the markers. My intention for taking Part 1 of Dynamic[point] is to get past the Dynamic Head to the list itself. I've tried With[{point=pt},...] and many other arrangements of the Dynamic calls with no luck. I can't believe this  fairly common task is so difficult, so I assume I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

In version 10.1 this sort of works, but the sliders are sticky; I have to click once to move them rather than click-and-drag.  I recall having this problem before (with `Slider`, not `HorizontalGauge`) but I cannot recall the cause or solution.  How does this behave in whatever version you are using?

```
ClearAll[h]
h[d_, opt___] := Dynamic[HorizontalGauge[d, opt]]

Manipulate[{pt}, {{pt, {0.6, 0.7}}, 0, 5, (h[##] &)}]
```

Comment: In version 12.0.0.0 on MacOS 10.13.6 I get what sounds like the same behavior. When I click in the gauge, the nearest marker moves to the position I clicked and the value of pt is updated. Dragging does nothing. Thanks, I can make this work in a pinch. Can you explain why the argument of h is not inside a Dynamic? Do you think it might be worth fiddling with mouse events to try getting click-and-drag to work?

Comment: Huh, this exhibits the same behavior, too:
    h[Dynamic[point_], opt___] := Dynamic[HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[point]]]
I just hadn't tried clicking outside the markers.

Comment: @Stephen (1) According to the specification of `Manipulate`: "The form `{u, umin, umax, func}` can also be used; what is evaluated is then `func[Dynamic[u], {umin, umax}]`."  Since it is already passed in a Dynamic head thought perhaps nesting a second one was a source of trouble.  (2) I feel like this should *just work* and wondered if it was a version-specific bug.  I don't know how to get it working, and the fact that you're trying to do this for a Demonstration adds restrictions that make alternatives difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the HorizontalGauge to work and resorted to using IntervalSlider for this problem after fixing the bug in my TrackingFunction. (Or rather, stumbling across a TrackingFunction that worked.) In my opinion, there's something fishy about passing List arguments in Manipulate